# AJAX and GET[] Dilemma

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using PHP Templates on my page by creating GET VARS which lead to a include() file. I have a commenting system on a blog page which sends an AJAX GET request on submit. However when the user clicks submit all the variables go to the url and my php template script doesn't recognize it and for security just redirects back to the home page. How do I avoid this?

**AJAX CODE:**

```
<script>
        function postComment() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }


            else {// code for IE6, IE5

                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("commentHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            var comment = document.getElementById("commenter").value;
            var id = document.getElementById("postID").value;
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "commentpost.php?comment=" + comment + "&postID=" + id, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }
        setTimeout("postComment()", 1000);

    </script>
    <form>
        <div id="comment">
            <textarea name="comment" id="commenter" rows="4" cols="125" style="max-width: 950px; max-height: 140px;" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION["name"] ?>, Write Your Comment Here" class="form-control"></textarea><br>
            <div id="commentHint"></div>
            <input type="submit" onclick="postComment()" value="Submit Comment"  class="btn btn-success btn-sm ">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>" id="postID">

        </div>
    </form>
```

**TEMPLATE CODE:**

```
               $p = $_GET["page"];
                if (preg_match("</^[a-zA-Z ]*$/>", $p)) {
                    session_start();
                    session_destroy();
                    header("location: index.php?error=2");
                } else {

                    switch ($p) {
                        case "2";
                            include("about.php");
                            break;
                        case "3";
                            include("games.php"); //CREATE PAGES
                            break;
                        case "4";
                            include("blog.php"); <== THIS PAGE IS THE BLOG PAGE
                            break;
                        case "5";
                            include("info.php");
                            break;
                        case "6";
                            include("settings.php");
                            break;
                        case "7";
                            include("functiontest.php");
                            break;
                        case "8";
                            include("styletech.php");
                            break;
                        case "9";
                            include("userlist.php");
                            break;
                        case "10";
                            include("adminpanel.php");
                            break;
                        case "11";
                            include("StyleTuts/styletech.php");
                            break;
                        default:
                            include("home.php");
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: $_GET["page"]; are you sure about this ? i don't see a variable with name page, I think you are intending to use postID, am I right ?

Comment: Using GET to post comments is horrible. Use - guess what - POST! Can you change blog.php so it uses `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: Can you put one return false; as the last statement inn script.

Comment: Can you try adding `page=4` in `commentpost.php?...`

Comment: The page keeps going back to home page even when I use the return false and POST Request
                xmlhttp.open("POST", "commentpost.php", true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send("page=4&comment=" + comment + "&postID=" + id);
                return false;